# Jquery Autocomplete no muestra nada

Tags: java, jquery

desde varios dias tengo el problema, que cuando llamo a la funcion autocomplete de jquery no me muestra nada, y ya he revisado las preguntas que otros ya han formulado, pero sigo sin darme cuenta cual es el problema, supongo que porque no tengo muy claro Javascript. Agradezco de antemano quien pueda echarme una mano!.

La funcion esta funcionando, de hecho he tratado seguirla con el debugger y aparentemente funciona. En mi vista, una pagina JSP,  tengo este codigo:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#cuenta").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    alert("pepe");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "CuentaBusca",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        minLength: 2,
                        delay: 100,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log( data);
                            response(data);
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

El console.log me muestra el resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el servlet tengo el siguiente codigo, que tambien funciona:

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    DBConexion conex = null;
    try {
        conex = new DBConexion();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Sucedio un Error al Realizar la Conexion a la Base de Datos !", ex);
    }

    Connection conn = conex.getConexion();

    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select id,nombre from cuentas order by nombre");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        JsonObject json_response = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray data_json = new JsonArray();

        while (rs.next()) {
            JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

            json.addProperty("id", rs.getInt("id"));
            json.addProperty("nombre", rs.getString("nombre"));
            data_json.add(json);
        }
        json_response.add("aaData", data_json);

        response.setContentType("application/Json");
        response.getWriter().write(json_response.toString());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Sucedio un Error al Realizar la Conexion a la Base de Datos !", ex);

    }

    // Cierra la Conexion 
    try {
        conex.closeConexion();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Sucedio un Error al Cerrar la Conexion en la Base de Datos !", ex);
    }
}
```

Yo sospecho que estoy retornando en un formato inadecuado desde el servlet, pero no encontre una explicacion mas clara.
Alguna idea?

Saludos,
Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude encontrar la solucion, no comprendia como debe ser el formato en la seccion "success" :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CuentaBusca",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cbocuenta').empty();
                    $.each(data.aaData, function (i, data) {
                        $('#cbocuenta').append('<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.nombre + '</option>');
                    });
                    $("#cbocuenta").val($('#cuenta').val());
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("some error");
                }
            });
```